# How to Hide Filter Option from a Filtered View

Tags: list-view, ifilter

I'm using query string filter to send values to a list. I'm filtering on the "ID" column. I'm also showing this ID column in the view, and so this ID is displayed with  a filter option.

[image: List View]

Is there any I way I can remove this filter option with Javascript/Jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set css class `class="ms-positionRelative"` as display none. 
One way to put in css that all filter dropdown will not be visible. 
If required for specific column ... try to find the div with above mentioned css class and hide it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should look something like this:

```
$('th div[name="ID"]').children().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

This disables all the elements in ID field's table header cell.

This would be the easiest approach as there are multiple controls inside that `div` that trigger the filter.